# How to get product image from magento database using magento api in Magento 1.9.2.2?

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, magento-1.9

I am trying to fetch complete data of products from magento database using magento soap api using this link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html

and using the following code:

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://xxxxxxx.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('test_role', 'password'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
print_r($result);
?>
```

I do get data of all the products in the inventory like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 24 [sku] => 123445 [name] => Burger [set] => 4 [type] => simple [category_ids] => Array ( [0] => 59 ) [website_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 25 [sku] => MG1456 [name] => Massage [set] => 4 [type] => simple [category_ids] => Array ( [0] => 63 ) [website_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 26 [sku] => 345666 [name] => Chicken Chilly [set] => 4 [type] => simple [category_ids] => Array ( [0] => 59 ) [website_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 27 [sku] => 23424 [name] => Chicken Biryani [set] => 4 [type] => simple [category_ids] => Array ( [0] => 59 ) [website_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 28 [sku] => 45567 [name] => Panner Chilly [set] => 4 [type] => simple [category_ids] => Array ( [0] => 59 ) [website_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 31 [sku] => S5GH488 [name] => Pizza [set] => 4 [type] => simple [category_ids] => Array ( [0] => 59 ) [website_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) )
```

But I ALSO NEED THE IMAGE OF EACH PRODUCT SO I CAN DISPLAY IT IN MY APP! PLEASE HELP!

Comment: If I can return all products in array, Is it useful?

Comment: yes i need images of all the products so i can display them in my app.. an associative array using entity_id of the product to map with the image would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have all the products in your `$result` array could loop through this and get the images.

As you can see in the [official Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.list.html) you retrieve the images like so, adjusted to your current script:

```php
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://xxxxxxx.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('test_role', 'password'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
$productImages = array();

// Getting all the product images
foreach($result as $product) {
    $productImages[] = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeMediaList($sessionId, $product->productId);
}

print_r($result);

// Show the product images array
print_r($productImages);
?>
```

Comment: I am trying this out right now please give me a few minutes.

Comment: i get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array . on this line:   $productImages[] = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeMediaList($sessionId, $product['product_id']);

Comment: You could instead try `$product->productId` .. I edited my sample code

Comment: its actually $product->product_id. The code works now thanks :)